# Does Google Maps website return the equivalent of the first result returned by Google Maps Geocoding API?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Does anyone know if Google Maps has any default settings in displaying the lat/lng of a search location?

I'm using the Google Maps Geocoding API to find geolocation lat/lng values for a user-inputted search address. I want to match the results to Google Maps as closely as possible - could it be as simple as always taking the first result returned by the API?

Example: If I search "Kassel" in Google Maps, lat/lng results are 51.3149724,9.3904035.

[Google Maps result for searching "Kassel"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qzUrq.jpg)

Searching using Google API leads to two results, where the first result's location value is closer to Google Maps than the second:

```
{
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "Kassel",
               "short_name" : "Kassel",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Kassel",
               "short_name" : "KS",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Hesse",
               "short_name" : "HE",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Germany",
               "short_name" : "DE",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "Kassel, Germany",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 51.36940509999999,
                  "lng" : 9.570128199999999
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 51.2603671,
                  "lng" : 9.3511015
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 51.3127114,
               "lng" : 9.4797461
            },
            "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 51.36940509999999,
                  "lng" : 9.570128199999999
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 51.2603671,
                  "lng" : 9.3511015
               }
            }
         },
         "place_id" : "ChIJHWx6n04_u0cRRxciWD1jhC8",
         "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
      },
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "Kassel",
               "short_name" : "Kassel",
               "types" : [ "sublocality_level_1", "sublocality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Biebergemünd",
               "short_name" : "Biebergemünd",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Darmstadt",
               "short_name" : "DA",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Hessen",
               "short_name" : "HE",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Germany",
               "short_name" : "DE",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "63599",
               "short_name" : "63599",
               "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "Kassel, 63599 Biebergemünd, Germany",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 50.2173498,
                  "lng" : 9.3059744
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 50.18299649999999,
                  "lng" : 9.271353399999999
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 50.2066898,
               "lng" : 9.279060399999999
            },
            "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 50.2173498,
                  "lng" : 9.286410699999999
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 50.2006739,
                  "lng" : 9.271353399999999
               }
            }
         },
         "place_id" : "ChIJG4zo1CMvvUcRQPWOqlJDIgo",
         "types" : [ "sublocality_level_1", "sublocality", "political" ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

The only documentation around this that I could find was as follows:

*Why do the Google Maps APIs Geocoders provide different locations than Google Maps?
The API geocoder and Google Maps geocoder sometimes use different data sets (depending on the country). The API geocoder occasionally gets updated with new data, so you can expect to see results changing or improving over time.*

https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#geocoder_differences

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Educated guess ahead)

I believe that Google Maps gives you results also based on previous map and location searches, from your account.

It is hard to believe they use the same API provided to developers without major improvements.

The results might also take in consideration previous web searches, your location and so on.

The developer API is simply a small set of functionality they use.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes I think I agree with you - it makes sense that the Google Maps functionality would be more powerful than the API. As user KENdi rightly pointed out, it would also depend on the domain you are searching from. So there's no simple answer I guess! Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

You could not exactly match your result to the Google Maps, because Google Maps Geocoding API returns address results influenced by the region (typically the country) from which the request is sent. For example, searches for "San Francisco" may return different results if sent from a domain within the United States than one sent from Spain.

Geocoding results can be biased for every domain in which the main Google Maps application is officially launched. Note that biasing only prefers results for a specific domain; if more relevant results exist outside of this domain, they may be included.

For more information click this [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#RegionCodes).

Comment: That makes sense for Google Maps, but I think for the API, unless you specify the region in the parameters, it will use the default of United States. In this case, I never set the "region" parameter that would influence the domain. It is true that matching the region in the API call to the domain used when searching on Google Maps (i.e., if I'm searching from Ireland on the Google Maps website, I should change the region to Ireland in my Google API call) would bring a better match in the order of results. I do not think it would be any guarantee of an exact match though. Thanks anyway!